# speed up modelling of subgroups in large data frame

Tags: r, performance, mixed-models

I need to perform an analysis with glmer on many different subgroups of a large dataset and only extract the estimate and z-value of each model. This works perfectly fine if I only use a small subset of my data (or some dummy data, as attached below), but when I try to include the whole data set, it takes forever. Currently I am using this bit of code:

```
slope_range <- df %>%
  group_by(region, year, species) %>%
  summarise(slope = coef(summary(glmer(presence ~ transect + (1 | road), family = "binomial")))[2],
            p_val = coef(summary(glmer(presence ~ transect + (1 | road), family = "binomial")))[6])
```

As I said, this works fine, but very slow on a large data set. I'm aware that I could also just write multiple loops, but I assume this would take even longer. Does anyone have a better solution of what could be done to make it faster? Thanks!

Dummy data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(region = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ARG", "CHE"), class = "factor"), 
    transect = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), presence = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), year = c(2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
    2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
    2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
    2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
    2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
    2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
    2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
    2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
    2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
    2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L), species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
    road = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("FG", "MK", "PL", "XY"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-160L))
```

Comment: How many unique combinations of `region, year, species` are there? If that number is large, your best bet is to utilize some type of parallel computing package and distribute the calculation based on some partition of those combinations. Regardless though, you're fitting each model twice in your code (you call `glmer` twice in `summarise`) so you could likely cut the time almost in half by only calling it once and saving both values of interest. I'm not a `tidyverse` user but I believe an element of a `tibble` can be a list so that would be one way to save both.

Comment: There's roughly 4500 combinations as there are many different species... I did notice I run that command twice, but wasn't sure how to avoid it (@qdread 's answer solves that). I'm not an expert in R etc. but I will definitely look into parallel computing packages as you suggest - thanks a lot!

Comment: regarding @ClancyStats comment, you might try the `furrr` package which can fairly easily parallelize your tidyverse code if written with `purrr` functions, without changing the syntax

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! Only problem I have: I can write my code with purrr only if I use ````lm()````or ````glm()````, as soon as I try to use ````lmer()```` I get an error - do you know whether thisis a general problem?

Comment: I am not sure what your error is coming from but you should also look into the `broom.mixed` package, still in development, which provides tidyverse methods for the class of model objects created by `lme4` functions: https://github.com/bbolker/broom.mixed

Comment: I will look into it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `coef(summary(glmer(...)))` twice for each group, so you can cut the execution time roughly in half by fitting the model and extracting the coefficients once for each group. The following code will extract all the coefficients and their Z and p-values, not just the two values you specified, which I think is preferable if you might end up needing them later. Of course it can be easily modified to discard the other coefficients and keep only the two you specified.

### code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

df %>%
  group_by(region, year, species) %>%
  group_modify(~ data.frame(variable = c('Intercept', 'transect'), 
                            coef(summary(glmer(presence ~ transect + (1 | road), family = "binomial", data = .)))))
```

### output

```
# A tibble: 16 x 8
# Groups:   region, year, species [8]
   region  year species variable  Estimate Std..Error z.value Pr...z..
   <fct>  <int> <fct>   <fct>        <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 ARG     2007 a       Intercept    6.11       2.81     2.17   0.0300
 2 ARG     2007 a       transect    -0.743      0.361   -2.06   0.0398
 3 ARG     2007 b       Intercept    1.91       1.22     1.57   0.116 
 4 ARG     2007 b       transect    -0.396      0.208   -1.90   0.0570
 5 ARG     2017 a       Intercept    3.95       1.73     2.28   0.0223
 6 ARG     2017 a       transect    -0.654      0.275   -2.38   0.0174
 7 ARG     2017 b       Intercept    2.44       1.33     1.83   0.0668
 8 ARG     2017 b       transect    -0.396      0.208   -1.90   0.0570
 9 CHE     2007 a       Intercept    3.95       1.73     2.28   0.0223
10 CHE     2007 a       transect    -0.654      0.275   -2.38   0.0174
11 CHE     2007 b       Intercept    2.44       1.33     1.83   0.0668
12 CHE     2007 b       transect    -0.396      0.208   -1.90   0.0570
13 CHE     2017 a       Intercept    6.11       2.81     2.17   0.0300
14 CHE     2017 a       transect    -0.743      0.361   -2.06   0.0398
15 CHE     2017 b       Intercept    1.91       1.22     1.57   0.116 
16 CHE     2017 b       transect    -0.396      0.208   -1.90   0.0570
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You could use a parallel approach as suggested earlier, e.g. with `parallel::mclapply` (on my 6-core machine using more than 4 cores gave only marginal improvements, though).
2. You could speed up glmer using `nAGQ=0`, at the cost of precision (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132841/default-lme4-optimizer-requires-lots-of-iterations-for-high-dimensional-data).

Example code with benchmarks:

```r
invisible(lapply(c("lme4", "data.table", "tidyverse", "parallel", "microbenchmark"),
    require, character.only = TRUE))  
#> Loading required package: lme4
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: data.table
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
#> Loading required package: parallel
#> Loading required package: microbenchmark

df <- structure(list(region = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ARG", "CHE"), class = "factor"), 
  transect = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), presence = c(1L, 1L, 
      1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
      0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
      0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
      0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
      1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
      1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
      1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
      0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
      0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
      0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), year = c(2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
        2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
        2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
        2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
        2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
        2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
        2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
        2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
        2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
        2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
        2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
        2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
        2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
        2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
        2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
        2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
        2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
        2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
        2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L), species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
          2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
          2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
          2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
  road = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
  ), .Label = c("FG", "MK", "PL", "XY"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -160L))

## Your function for comparison
tidy_fun <- function(){
  df %>%
    group_by(region, year, species) %>%
    summarise(slope = coef(summary(glmer(presence ~ transect + (1 | road), family = "binomial")))[2],
      p_val = coef(summary(glmer(presence ~ transect + (1 | road), family = "binomial")))[6])  
} 


gf2 <- function(presence, transect, road, nAGQ = 1L) {
  res <- coef(summary(glmer(presence ~ transect + (1 | road), family = "binomial", nAGQ=nAGQ)))
  return(data.table(slope=res[2], p_val=res[6]))
} 

parLM <- function(mc.cores=4L, nAGQ=1L){
  DT <- data.table(df, key = c("region","year","species"))
  iDT <- DT[,by=.(region, year, species),.(irange=.(range(.I)))]
  result <- mclapply(seq(nrow(iDT)), 
    function(x) DT[do.call(seq, as.list(iDT[x, irange][[1]])), 
      .(gf2(presence, transect, road, nAGQ=nAGQ))], mc.cores=mc.cores)
  return(cbind(iDT, rbindlist(result))[,-4])
}  

microbenchmark(
  original = suppressMessages(tidy_fun()),
  multicore = parLM(mc.cores = 4L, nAGQ = 1L),
  singlecore.nAGQ0 = parLM(mc.cores = 1L, nAGQ = 0L),
  multicore.nAGQ0 = parLM(mc.cores = 4L, nAGQ = 0L),
  times=10L)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#>          original 898.2732 925.0621 963.7452 940.9577 973.0648 1157.0030    10
#>         multicore 319.1234 334.4151 347.8024 344.1370 362.6539  373.8189    10
#>  singlecore.nAGQ0 237.4782 245.4084 262.6290 268.1308 274.8516  280.7944    10
#>   multicore.nAGQ0 132.3356 132.9963 137.2777 135.8659 141.5145  144.2564    10
#>   cld
#>     d
#>    c 
#>   b  
#>  a
```

Comment: This is also great, thanks! Good to know there are so many different ways to speed things up.